# Spring MVC : how to get the mapped URI within a method marked with @RequestMapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm currently working on a Spring MVC application and as I mapped, within the web.xml file, all incoming URL to a single DispatcherServlet, I wanted to know whether it would be possible to retrieve the URI that has been effectively mapped. Here's an example to illustrate my concerns :

```
import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {


    @RequestMapping(method={GET})
    public String processAllRequest(){
        return "viewName";
    }
}
```

Since I've defined the URL-MAPPING in the web.xml as being "/*", all incoming requests will end up in my controller class, show above. For instance, both the following requests will be processed by the processAllRequest() method from my controller.

- myApplicationContext/home
- myApplicationContext/logout

Is it possible, somehow, to retrieve the mapped URI? That is, once I'm inside the processAllRequest(), how could I know if it's been called for .../home or .../logout?
Is it possible to retrieve this kind of info by injecting an HttpServletRequest or another object as argument of the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have formulated my question in an ambiguous way but what I was looking for, was rather path variable. So my problem was solved this way :

@Controller
public class HomeController {

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{uri}", method={GET})
public String processMappedUri(@PathVariable uri){
    return uri;
}
```

}

With this solution whenever I request the following requests, the uri argument from my processMappedUri() method will hold the variable value :

- myApplicationContext/home --> uri = home
- myApplicationContext/logout --> uri = logout

Answer (score 2):

Spring does inject `HttpServletRequest` if you put it in your handler arguments, so you can do that if you like.

But if you need to distinguish between different URLs, just place them in different handlers:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/home", method={GET})
    public String processHome(){
        return "viewName";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method={GET})
    public String processLogin(){
        return "viewName";
    }
}
```

The mapping in web.xml forwards all requests to the spring servlet. You can still write as many `@Controller`s as you like, and play with class-level and method-level `@RequestMapping` to split the application into logical components.